# Displaying Data from databse in XML format in JSF

Tags: xml, spring, hibernate, jsf

I am working on a Java web application with Spring Hibernate ORM +JSF2.0 .I need to get data from database(MySQL) and display it in XML format (with nodes and sub-nodes) on a JSF page.

In Managed Bean, I am returning the data in an arraylist 'al'. In JSF i want to iterate this list and dispaly data in XML tags as shown below.Please suggest me how to show it on JSF/.xhtml page.

```
    public ArrayList<BusServiceBean> listBus()
    {
       BusServiceBean buservs=new BusServiceBean();
       BusService bus=(BusService)ServiceFinder.findBean("busDaoTarget");
       ArrayList<BusServiceBean> al= bus.listBus(buservs);
       return al;   
     }
```

Example given below,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
-<markers>
 -<marker>
 <BUSNAME>202ST1</BUSNAME> 
 <OWNER>Tata Power</OWNER> 
 <AREA>South</AREA> 
 <KVLEVEL>400</KVLEVEL> 
 <STATUS>In Service</STATUS> 
 <LATITUDE>17.30868788677</LATITUDE> 
 <LONGITUDE>78.7060546875</LONGITUDE> 
</marker>
-<marker>
  <BUSNAME>302ST2</BUSNAME> 
  <OWNER>NTPC</OWNER> 
  <AREA>Western India</AREA> 
  <KVLEVEL>400</KVLEVEL> 
  <STATUS>In Service</STATUS> 
  <LATITUDE>23.7652368897587</LATITUDE> 
  <LONGITUDE>71.630859375</LONGITUDE> 
 </marker>
</markers>
```

Comment: You mean, embedded in e.g. a `<pre>` tag in a JSF page, or as the whole response? If the whole response, why are you using JSF in first place instead of e.g. JAX-RS or maybe Spring MVC?

Comment: BaluC thanks for your reply, I do need a whole response. I am not aware of JAX-RS.I am using Spring 3.0 MVC as front end technology and Hibernate as backend ORM. I want to diplay data in xml form as shown above. If you know any possible method to do it please reply.

Comment: Spring MVC alone is capable of this. Why the need for JSF here?

Comment: Thanks I got the point. Now I know where I was going wrong, got the problem resolved.